# extracting substring separated by '-'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am extracting substring separated by '-'.
i have dropdown in this format given below(two dropdown items)
123- hi sam,
U23- hi dany
want to extract the text after '-' eg. hi sam & hi dany on selecting the dropdown
but getting '-' along with text eg. - hi sam & - hi dany

```js
$(document).on("change", "#upcList", function (e) {
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var modselcttext=selectedText.match("-(.*)");
});
```

kindly suggest what modification neeed to be done so that '-' will not include in extracted text.

Comment: It seems correct use modselcttext[1]

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava - interesting, I did not know you could do that with a string in `match` (jaromanda reads documentation ... )

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes match matches whole expressions and all the sub groups that are in capture mode (Capture mode is in round brackets); if you do not want something in capture mode you just add (?:'followed by expression') now this will not be captured as separate string in array

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava - I just never realised a non "regex" as the first argument is converted to a regex using `new Regex` ... I know how match works though ... :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Lol we learn new things every day :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
selectedText.split('-')[1]
```

Comment: the result would be different (than OP's attempt with regex) for ... `abc-def-ghi` for example :p

Comment: the equivalent to the OP's regex would be `selectedText.split('-').slice(1).join('-')`